# Image push notification is not working IOS

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

UNNotificationServiceExtension is not getting called when i am trying to call the following custom payload data.

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": {
            "title": "Hello",
            "body": "body.."
        },
        "mutable-content":1,
        "sound": "default",
        "badge": 1,

    },
"data": {
  "attachment-url": "https://pusher.com/static_logos/320x320.png"

},
}
```

But when i call this below custom payload data,then UNNotificationServiceExtension is getting called

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": {
            "title": "Hello",
            "body": "body.."
        },
        "mutable-content":1,
        "sound": "default",
        "badge": 1,

    },
"data": {
  "attachment-url": ""

},
}
```

My problem is that if i put any http url in attachment-url key then UNNotificationServiceExtension it's not getting called but if i put sometext or leave it as empty instead of Url then it's will call.
I am sending custom payload from https://pushtry.com/ 
Here is my NotificationServiceExtension class

```
import UserNotifications

class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {

    var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
    var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

    override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
        self.contentHandler = contentHandler
        bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)

        // Get the custom data from the notification payload
        if let notificationData = request.content.userInfo["data"] as? [String: String] {
            // Grab the attachment
            if let urlString = notificationData["attachment-url"], let fileUrl = URL(string: urlString) {
                // Download the attachment
                URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: fileUrl) { (location, response, error) in
                    if let location = location {
                        // Move temporary file to remove .tmp extension
                        let tmpDirectory = NSTemporaryDirectory()
                        let tmpFile = "file://".appending(tmpDirectory).appending(fileUrl.lastPathComponent)
                        let tmpUrl = URL(string: tmpFile)!
                        try! FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: tmpUrl)

                        // Add the attachment to the notification content
                        if let attachment = try? UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: "", url: tmpUrl) {
                            self.bestAttemptContent?.attachments = [attachment]
                        }
                    }
                    // Serve the notification content
                    self.contentHandler!(self.bestAttemptContent!)
                    }.resume()
            }
        }    }

    override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
        // Called just before the extension will be terminated by the system.
        // Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be used.
        if let contentHandler = contentHandler, let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }

}
extension UNNotificationAttachment {

    /// Save the image to disk
    static func create(imageFileIdentifier: String, data: NSData, options: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> UNNotificationAttachment? {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let tmpSubFolderName = ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString
        let tmpSubFolderURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(tmpSubFolderName, isDirectory: true)

        do {
            try fileManager.createDirectory(at: tmpSubFolderURL!, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            let fileURL = tmpSubFolderURL?.appendingPathComponent(imageFileIdentifier)
            try data.write(to: fileURL!, options: [])
            let imageAttachment = try UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: imageFileIdentifier, url: fileURL!, options: options)
            return imageAttachment
        } catch let error {
            print("error \(error)")
        }

        return nil
}
}
```

Comment: the above payloads arent proper JSON but I guess thats not really it!?

Comment: @Daji-Djan : I think they are proper .If you have any custom payload then give it to me. It will check.